# Building .htm email signatures with PHP or script and Active Directory

Tags: php, scripting, outlook, html, vbscript

We use HTML signatures which are based off a template which gets changed from time to time.

At the moment i have to open all the html files stored on the server into dreamweaver or similar, make the change to a users .htm file then to a find and replace accross the other files, which seems a dirty way of doing it.

What id like to do is use php or some form of script to pull user details from active directory then insert into a template a bit like a winword mailmerge so that when i make a change i can rebuild everyones signatures from scratch using the original template i just edited.

Hope that makes sense. Is this possible with php or would some kind of vbscript be able to achieve the same thing. Not sure where to start, if anyone can give me some pointers that would be great,

I know there are packages out there to manage things like this but the company wouldnt justify the expense.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good starting point:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.10.heyscriptingguy.aspx

or this one saves in different formats:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/2ab97854-cf06-4639-8556-16dcda10d851

Comment: thanks, that should get me going, would have liked to have avoided word all together as it fills the .htm files with extra rubbish. Would it theoretically be possible to do the same typetext kind of stuff but but in notepad, and then just stuff in the actual HTML/CSS code?

Comment: This might be better: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_24256332.html

Scroll to the bottom of the page and use the reply from 'sirbounty'

Answer (score 0):

The open source project GenerateSignatureFromLDAP was written with exactly this in mind: generating Outlook signatures based on a template and values taken from Active Directory.
See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gensignfromldap/